# Pass data in onclick function in Jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am facing a problem in Jquery ajax...

I want to pass a value in a function, this is my code:

```
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
    id = value['req_id'];
    notification.onclick = function () {
        alert(id);return false;

        $.ajax({
            url     : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>dashboard/notificationUpdated",
            type    : 'post',
            data    : {'id':id},
            dataType: "json",
            success : function(data){}
        });     
    };
});
```

when id is  alerted it shows "undefined". How to solve this ,i want to pass this value to controller....
Can anyone help me with this???
Waiting for a response........

data  =>

```
{  
   "0":{  
      "req_id":"368"
   },
   "1":{  
      "req_id":"371"
   },
   "2":{  
      "req_id":"372"
   },
   "3":{  
      "req_id":"373"
   },
   "4":{  
      "req_id":"375"
   },
   "5":{  
      "req_id":"376"
   },
   "6":{  
      "req_id":"378"
   },
   "7":{  
      "req_id":"379"
   },
   "8":{  
      "req_id":"380"
   },
   "9":{  
      "req_id":"382"
   },
   "10":{  
      "req_id":"385"
   },
   "11":{  
      "req_id":"386"
   },
   "12":{  
      "req_id":"387"
   },
   "13":{  
      "req_id":"399"
   },
   "14":{  
      "req_id":"400"
   },
   "15":{  
      "req_id":"404"
   },
   "16":{  
      "req_id":"405"
   },
   "17":{  
      "req_id":"406"
   },
   "18":{  
      "req_id":"418"
   },
   "19":{  
      "req_id":"419"
   },
   "20":{  
      "req_id":"422"
   },
   "21":{  
      "req_id":"424"
   },
   "22":{  
      "req_id":"425"
   },
   "23":{  
      "req_id":"428"
   },
   "24":{  
      "req_id":"429"
   },
   "25":{  
      "req_id":"430"
   },
   "26":{  
      "req_id":"431"
   },
   "27":{  
      "req_id":"432"
   },
   "28":{  
      "req_id":"434"
   },
   "status":"success"
}
```

Comment: `put console.log(value)` to show what it returned

Comment: outside onclick function id is printed ,but inside function it shows undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
                   var id = value['req_id'];
                   notification.onclick = function () {
                     alert(id);

                      $.ajax({
                        url     : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>dashboard/notificationUpdated",
                        type    : 'post',
                        data    : { id: id },
                        dataType: "json",
                        success : function(data){}
                      });

                };
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use id as below

```
id=data[index].req_id;
```

pass id paramater into function

remove the `return false` from the code

Comment: $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                   id = value['req_id'];
                 notification.onclick (id);
                });
  notification.onclick = function (id) {
                     alert(id);return false;

                      $.ajax({
                        url     : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>dashboard/notificationUpdated",
                        type    : 'post',
                        data    : {'id':id},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success : function(data){}
                      });

                };

Comment: declare function outside the loop and call it from loop

Comment: shows error " TypeError: notification.onclick is not a function "

Answer (score 1):

Hello Try with below code it will be help you, here it display error of data variable but dont worry about it. because you have already declared and have value :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.each(data, function (index, value) {
  $(notification).click(function () {
   id = value['req_id'];
   alert(id);return false;
   $.ajax({
    url     : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>dashboard/notificationUpdated",
    type    : 'post',
    data    : {'id':id},
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(data){}
   });

  });
 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you add data variable in your question description?